# Installing MySQL-python raises compiler warnings after Mavericks

Tags: macos, python, osx-mavericks

I had many python modules installed before I upgraded Mavericks and were very disappointed when I noticed that they had been removed. I installed Mavericks, and I installed the command line tools.

Then I went on trying to download and compile MySQL-python since I need it for my development. It raises compiler warnings during install and then just freezes.

Here are the compiler warnings:

```
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.4.zip (113kB): 113kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
    Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.28.tar.gz
    Extracting in /tmp/tmpYaLRd4
    Now working in /tmp/tmpYaLRd4/distribute-0.6.28
    Building a Distribute egg in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python
    /private/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg

Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
  Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
    building '_mysql' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing
    clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/include/my_config.h:348:11: warning: 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T' macro redefined
      #define SIZEOF_SIZE_T  SIZEOF_LONG
              ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:43:17: note: previous definition is here
    #        define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           8
                    ^
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/include/my_config.h:442:9: warning: 'HAVE_WCSCOLL' macro redefined
    #define HAVE_WCSCOLL
            ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:906:9: note: previous definition is here
    #define HAVE_WCSCOLL 1
            ^
    _mysql.c:287:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    cmd_argc = PySequence_Size(cmd_args);
                             ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:317:12: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    groupc = PySequence_Size(groups);
                           ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:470:14: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            int j, n2=PySequence_Size(fun);
                                   ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1105:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1107:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_escape_string(out, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1146:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            size = PyString_GET_SIZE(s);
                 ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:92:32: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_GET_SIZE'
    #define PyString_GET_SIZE(op)  Py_SIZE(op)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/object.h:116:56: note: expanded from macro 'Py_SIZE'
    #define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1156:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_real_escape_string(&(self->connection), out+1, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1158:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                    len = mysql_escape_string(out+1, in, size);
                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1252:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            if ((n = PyObject_Length(o)) == -1) goto error;
                   ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:434:25: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_Length'
    #define PyObject_Length PyObject_Size
                            ^
    _mysql.c:1444:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            len = strlen(buf);
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1446:10: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                            len = strlen(buf);
                                ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1482:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                    len = strlen(buf);
                                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1484:11: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
                                    len = strlen(buf);
                                        ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
    _mysql.c:1567:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
            if (how < 0 || how >= sizeof(row_converters)) {
                ~~~ ^ ~
    16 warnings generated.
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/include/my_config.h:348:11: warning: 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T' macro redefined
      #define SIZEOF_SIZE_T  SIZEOF_LONG
              ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:56:17: note: previous definition is here
    #        define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           4
                    ^
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/include/my_config.h:442:9: warning: 'HAVE_WCSCOLL' macro redefined
    #define HAVE_WCSCOLL
            ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:906:9: note: previous definition is here
    #define HAVE_WCSCOLL 1
            ^
    In file included from _mysql.c:44:
    /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/include/my_config.h:659:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_TIME_T' macro redefined
    #define SIZEOF_TIME_T 8
            ^
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:57:17: note: previous definition is here
    #        define SIZEOF_TIME_T           4
                    ^
    _mysql.c:1567:10: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
            if (how < 0 || how >= sizeof(row_converters)) {
                ~~~ ^ ~
    4 warnings generated.
```

Seems like it complains on a lot of variables already defined. But I don't know how to solve these problems since I don't really know what's going on. And I don't think trying to edit the source will give me any good answers.

I have tried to use both pip and easy_install to install the extension. Both generate warnings and freezes. Please help me :)